# Is it possible to make HTTP requests when app is closed?

Tags: ios, push-notification, background-process

I am working on an app, and a crucial part of the functionality is that it must make HTTP GET requests with my backend server. When there is a new update in form of a string, then it will set the clipboard as that string. The problem is that the user is not supposed to have my app in the foreground, it is thought more of a background task.

So I need some method to achieve this functionality when the app is in the background or even closed. The problem with Background Fetch is that it only updates once every 30 minutes at least. I need to achieve this check every 10 seconds or something. I was thinking of social media apps like WhatsApp, Messenger or even Facebook. Even if you close the app itself, you will still receive a notification when there is a new message. So it means that somehow, these apps do check for new incoming messages very frequently (at least every 5 sec).

So maybe I can use the Push Notification method to make the same functionality? Is it possible?

Comment: _So it means that somehow, these apps do check for new incoming messages very frequently..._ No, they just receive Push Notification from the server, they don't ping the server for updates. If app _even close_ - don't think it's possible.

Comment: Okay, but that's fine. If they receive a Push Notification from my server, then can I put some logic code to be executed upon the arrival of the Push Notification? It's just one simple line of code: setClipboard(incomingtxt).

Answer (score 0):

You can also call call api with background task but you to call it in the background thread. But push notification is a much more better solution.

Comment: And it is possible to execute some code upon arrival of a push notification right?